# fopen fails after changing console app to windows app

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 on Windows XP Professional with Visual Studio
10(Ultimate) and I'm having trouble opening the cascade files.

The relevant code is the following:

```
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ message(TEXT("--(!)Error loading face\n"));
```

I'm making sure that the current directory is correct using the
`GetCurrentDirectory()` function and the xml file is contained in that directory.

The funny thing is, the program works correctly when I compile and run it in
*Console* mode but I get the error "Error loading face" when I run it under
Win32 mode(no console).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try running filemon from sysinternals to see what file accesses your windows app is really doing.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it's being called internally by face_cascade.load(). Maybe it's some other function. I know the same code works when I run it as a console app. But when I put it into a Windows App and call this code from WndProc it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the filemon advice. I installed the successor(Process Monitor) and the fileName is garbled the directory path is correct but the final fileName is garbled.

Comment: Here is what the garbled file looks like:
`F:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloWin\Debug\øB`


Correct would be:
`F:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloWin\Debug\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`

Comment: It started working after I changed the configuration from "Debug" to "Release". But did it have this problem in "Debug" configuration?

Answer (score 0):

According to the OpenCV documentation the CascadeClassification object has a load method with the following prototype:

```
bool CascadeClassifier::load(const string& filename)
```

but you are feeding it a `String`. It looks from your comment like it has simply appended the pointer value to the directory string. Try giving it the correct type of argument. ie:

```
string face_cascade_name("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
if( !face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name) { ... }
```